# How to implement several nested and interdependent subscriptions with RxJS operators?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, rxjs6

I have nested subscription that I would like to get rid of using a suitable [RxJS](https://www.learnrxjs.io/) operator. I have already tried [concatMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmap.html) and [mergeMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html) with which I unfortunately could not solve my problem.

I have 3 subscriptions that depend on each other and trigger a new observable within the forEach loops for each value of the current loop. To illustrate this in more detail, here is my sample code:

```
this.subscriptionOne = this.serviceOne.getStreets().subscribe((streets) => {
  streets.forEach((street) => {
    this.subscriptionTwo = this.serviceTwo.getMetaData(street.id).subscribe((metaDatas) => {
      metaDatas.forEach((md) => {
        // do some stuff and then trigger another observable..
        this.subscriptionThree = this.serviceTwo.getStuff(md.id, md.type, md.name).subscribe((stuff) => {
          // do some other stuff
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

How can I get rid of this nesting with RxJs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
let sub = this.serviceOne
  .getStreets()
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(streets => {
      return from(streets);
    }),
    mergeMap(street => {
      return this.serviceTwo.getMetaData(street.id);
    }),
    mergeMap(metaDatas => {
      return from(metaDatas);
    }),
    mergeMap(md => {
      return this.serviceTwo.getStuff(md.id, md.type, md.name);
    }),
    map(stuff => {
      // do your stuff
    })
  )
  .subscribe();
```

`metaDatas` available in the last two operators:

```
let sub = this.serviceOne
  .getStreets()
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(streets => {
      return from(streets);
    }),
    mergeMap(street => {
      return this.serviceTwo.getMetaData(street.id);
    }),
    mergeMap(metaDatas => {
      return from(metaDatas).pipe(
        mergeMap(md => {
          return this.serviceTwo.getStuff(md.id, md.type, md.name);
        }),
        map(stuff => {
          // do your stuff
        })
      );
    })
  )
  .subscribe();
```

Comment: So there are no more foreach grinding necessary? Then probably that's my mistake .. I'll test your approach later and give you a feedback. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you don't need `forEach` anymore.

Comment: Is there also a way to merge the last two mergeMap's or can I still access/iterate over 'metaDatas' within the subscribe function? Because after calling getStuff() in the last mergeMap I still need some properties from 'metaDatas' to generate the options for a final object.

Comment: You can preserve `metaDatas` in a variable, which belongs to the method containing the entire subscription or, of course, you can enclose the last two operators in a parent operator.

Comment: If you want to unwrap arrays like `streets` you have to turn them into Observables with `from(streets)` or you can just return an array and `mergeMap` will re-emit each item separately `mergeMap(streets => streets)` (well, or use `mergeAll` instead).

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I needed. Many Thanks!